# Internal camera rotated by 90° after opening a link in a new tab and redirection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, microsoft-edge

I've got the exact same issue as described here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14769888/

I've written a custom portal that on button push opens a second tab and browses to the video conferencing web bridge. the link however includes custom variables that then redirect the new tab to a specific conference.

once redirected the web cam image is rotated 90 degrees.

this only happens in Microsoft EDGE

does anyone know of a work around ? or if this bug has been fixed as it doesn't seem like it.

I'm unable to sign into the Microsoft developers page as it seems to conflict with my O365 account.

I'm using
Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0

Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

on Windows 10 pro 64bit

the link above does have sample code here [code](https://github.com/wpp/edge90) that I tested as well. Here is my page [Link to page](https://portal.cloudrooms.co.za/pages/uservmr.aspx?callID=528446&token=49250) that I wrote, just click on "join via browser" then enter a name and click join. it will then bring up a system check where you can see the camera is rotated.

Comment: Can you please inform us, Which exact version of MS Edge and which OS build version you are using currently? If possible for you than can you please post a sample code which can produce the issue. The link you had mentioned was too old and it mentioned that Edge 16 had this issue. If you are using any older version than I suggest you to update to latest version of MS Edge and again try to produce the issue. Let me know about your testing result and the necessary information that I ask above may help us to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: Hi Deepak, I've edited my post. I've also added a realtime example.

Comment: Please check my reply on your MSDN forum thread. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c74f3dab-ef29-49f0-866b-5d2e871bbcc7/internal-camera-rotated-by-90-after-opening-a-link-in-a-new-tab-and-redirection?forum=iewebdevelopment